# Video Editing software to add voice track

Tags: windows, video-editing

We have a video (currently in MP4 format) that has existing backing track to it, and needs narration. So effectively, we just want to add the narration to the video.

We don't want to compress it any more than we need to or remove any existing audio, so we just need a simple editor to add the additional audio.

We don't need anything amazing, just something that isn't going to compress the video any further, and no watermarks either (if there is a cost, that's fine, so long as it's not more than $100 AUD).

If more information is needed about fps, bit rates, etc. let me know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[OpenShot Video Editor](https://www.openshot.org/) is a free semi-pro tool that should meet your needs.